# how to convert string into the integer value if the data is present in text format in a .txt file and use it for a condition?

Tags: java

```
package com.example.test;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Student {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("abc.txt");        
        pw.println("ID   |   NAME   |   CITY        |   GRADE   |   AGE");
        FileReader fr1 = new FileReader("data_10.txt"); 
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(fr1);
        String line1 = br1.readLine();

        while (line1 != null) {
            boolean cond1 = false;
            boolean cond2 = false;
            boolean cond3 = false;
            FileReader fr2 = new FileReader("Scholership.txt");
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(fr2);
            String line2 = br2.readLine();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line1);
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s");
            String[] s = p.split(line1);
            String[] s1 = p.split(line2);

            for (String str:s) {
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("MUMBAI")) {
                    cond1=true; 
                }
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("C") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("D")) {
                    cond2=true;
                }       
                if (cond1 && cond2) {
                    System.out.println(line1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            line1 = br1.readLine();
        }
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
    }
}
```

There are 3 data files `data_10.txt`, `data_11.txt`, `data_12.txt` of class 10th, 11th, 12th respectively, which contains students data in 
Given format (separated by pipe)

```
Id|Name|city|Grade|Age
s001|Rohan|mumbai|A|16
```

There is another file which contains scholarship Info (scholarship.txt) (not all the students get scholarship)

```
Id|Family_Income|No_Of_Members
s013|2000|10
```

Write a java program to find out all the scholarship getting students who got either C or D grade and who are from 'Mumbai' and whose Family_Income < 5000

Comment: how can i just modify the code so that its start working.and how just seprate a string using pipe symbol?

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

See this [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) for more info.

Comment: what if a txt file contain string value mixed with integer value then it will give me the parseException..

Answer (score 0):

You want to split on the pipe symbol not whitespace, your pattern should be:

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\|");
```

You should also trim before comparing:

```
str.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("MUMBAI");
```

Comment: ok i should make a pattern of pipe.But there is a third file "scholership.txt" than how just i extract those  "5000" value in family income block to my condition.please help me out.